# What is driveWriteVolume rateMax?

Tags: google-apps-script

I recently started getting this exception:

```
driveWriteVolume rateMax. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls
```

Usually this means that I'm trying to access a service to quickly in repetition. However, I have never seen this message before and any searches I have made don't return any useful information about it.

Here is the best mockup I could do without pasting 100 lines of code:

```
function compileLabel(){
   var doc = DocsList.createFile('My Label', '', 'text/html');
   var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('My Label');

   var startTime = Date.now();
   while((Date.now() - startTime) < 240000){

     for(t in threads){
        var messages = threads[t].getMessages();
        var threadHeader = createThreadHeader(); //Builds HTML representation of thread info as string
        doc.append(threadHeader);

        for(m in messages){
           var msgHeader = createMessageHeader(); //Builds HTML representation from header info as string
           doc.append(msgHeader);
           doc.append(messages[i].getBody());

           var attachments = messages[m].getAttachments();
           if(attachments.length > 0){
              var attachmentFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(messages[m].getSubject());
           }
           for(a in attachments){
             attachmentFolder.createFile(attachments[a]);
           }
        }
     }
   }

   parentFolder.createFile(doc.getAs('application/pdf')); //this is intermittantly throwing an exception about serialization now, but that's probably a different issue.
   //After time based loop, do more things that don't have any DocsList based functions
}
```

As of 2 days ago, this worked very well. Now, unless I `sleep(1000)` before every `doc.append()`, `createFile()` or `createFolder()`, it produces this error. I can provide a project key if necessary.

Comment: Can you share the code where this is coming up from? When did you start seeing this?

Comment: What is the max rate at which I can use the DocsList or DriveApp service?

Comment: Searching for "driveWriteVolume" returns no results in the official Google developer documentation. Furstrating.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the same error mails today, apparently I exceeded the allowed upload rate to Google Drive. To fix it I had to increase the sleep time to 3000 (I was already using 1000). This is the piece of code that caused the error:

```
  var att = messages[y].getAttachments(); 
  var attlinks = [];  
  for (var z=0; z<att.length; z++) {
    try {
      var file = folder.createFile(att[z]); //create file in gdrive
      attlinks.push('<a href="'+file.getUrl()+'" target="_blank" alt="'+file.getName()+'">'+file.getName()+'</a>'); //push link to array
      Utilities.sleep(3000); //increased from 1000 to 3000
    }
```

**update**

I had to increase the sleep time once more (to 10s) because the issue still occurred when there were more than 5 attachments.