# script exceeding driveWriteVolume rateMax

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-sheets, google-apps

I have a piece of code that is supposed to create a folder for each email message in a thread, and save the body (as a pdf) and all the attachments (as whatever they are) into that folder.

If I run it without the loop for saving the attachments, I have no problem.  (Well, I have a different problem for a different thread).  If I uncomment the attachments loop, I get

`Service invoked too many times in a short time: driveWriteVolume rateMax. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls. (line 156, file "Code")`

All lines that create a folder or a file are followed by a `Utilities.sleep(sleepTime);` and sleeptime is currently set to 1000.  Changing it doesn't seem to have any effect.

The offending piece of code is:

```
        // Save attachments
        for(var i = 0; i < messageAttachments.length; i++) {
          var attachmentBlob = messageAttachments[i].copyBlob();
          newFolder.createFile(attachmentBlob);
          Utilities.sleep(sleepTime);  // wait after creating something on the drive.
        } // each attachment
```

it is the `newFolder.createFile(attachmentBlob);` line that triggers the error.

I have looked at [What is driveWriteVolume rateMax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469533/what-is-drivewritevolume-ratemax) and [Intermittant DriveWriteVolume rateMax exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694715/intermittant-drivewritevolume-ratemax-exception) for help, and have found none.

Note that if I comment out the loop for attachments, and just save the messages bodies as PDF, I have no problem, regardless of the number of emails I'm saving.  When I get the error, the script has died right where it should have saved the first attachment.  So I'm thinking there is something else wrong than exceeding some sort of limit.

Answer (score 0):

Your hitting a rate limit. Google api probably has a limit of approx 20 writes / minute, so you'll need to slow your script down in order to avoid triggering the rate limit. In [What is driveWriteVolume rateMax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469533/what-is-drivewritevolume-ratemax) the user in the similar thread used a time of 3000 ms to solve the problem rather than the suggested 1000 ms.

Comment: I have tried setting it as high as 3000 with no joy.  Why would I be hitting a limit when saving attachments with 3sec pauses but not when saving messages with no pause at all?